# Why my boolean function result is not recognized in main function

Tags: c

so I'm trying to build an ATM program, and I can't really understand why my code isn't working.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool accessCheck(int);

const int pin =1234;

int main(){
    int code, access;
    printf("Hi, please enter your password:");
    scanf("%d",&code);
    
    accessCheck(code);
    if(accessCheck(code)==1){
        printf("Password recognized.");
    }
    else {
        printf("Password unrecognized.");
    }
    return 0;   
}

bool accessCheck(int x){
    bool access=0;
    if(x == pin){
        bool access = 1;
    }
    return access;
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `accessCheck(code)` twice?

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring new variable `access` inside the `if` block. This shadows the variable with the same name in the main block of `accessCheck`.

You should just assign that variable rather than declaring another variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool accessCheck(int);

const int pin =1234;

int main(){
    int code;
    printf("Hi, please enter your password:");
    scanf("%d",&code);

    if(accessCheck(code)){
        printf("Password recognized.");
    }
    else {
        printf("Password unrecognized.");
    }
    return 0;
}

bool accessCheck(int x){
    bool access=false;
    if(x == pin){
        access = true;
    }
    return access;
}
```

Since you're using `stdbool` you can use `true` and `false` instead of `1` and `0`.

There's no need to call `accessCheck()` before the `if` statement.

Comment: To add to this answer: it's possible for some compilers to enable warnings for shadowed variables, for example using `-Wshadow`.